# How to send a class through named pipe in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, serialization, named-pipes

Using VB2008, I have 2 applications on 2 computers that needs to communicate. I setup a named pipe and so far, it's working. I can send strings, back and forth between those 2 programs.

Now, I need to be able to send a class, or an object. I have read somewhere that Serialization is the way to go. So, on the client, I have:

```
Public Class cTest

    Dim Var1 As Boolean
    Dim Var2 As String = "a test"
    Dim Var3 As New Collections.ArrayList

    Public Sub AddItem(ByVal Item As String)
        Var3.Add(Item)
    End Sub

End Class

Private Sub Button8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click

        Dim oClasse As New cTest

        oClasse.AddItem("StarWars")
        oClasse.AddItem("StarTrek")

        oPipe.SendToPipe(oClasse)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Sub SendToPipe(ByVal test As cTest)

        Dim xmlTest As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(cTest))
        xmlTest.Serialize(pipeClient, test)

    End Sub
```

On the server side (on the remote computer):

```
Public Function ReadString() As String

        Dim len As Integer = 0
        len = CType(ioStream.ReadByte(), Integer) * 256
        len += CType(ioStream.ReadByte(), Integer)

        Try
            Dim serializer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(cTest))
            Dim Test As cTest

            Test = CType(serializer.Deserialize(ioStream), cTest)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

End Function
```

The serializer.Deserialize throw an exception saying the XML format is not correct.

what I'm doing wrong?

thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

finally, after a lot of testing and googling, I figured it out:

when using the following code on the client side it works:

```
Dim oClasse As New cTest

oClasse.AddItem("StarWars")
oClasse.AddItem("StarTrek")

Using PStream As IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream = New IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream(".", "VisionEnginePipeRead1", PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.None, TokenImpersonationLevel.None)
            PStream.Connect()
            Dim xmlTest As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(cTest))
            xmlTest.Serialize(PStream, oClasse)
End Using
```

and this, on the server side:

```
Dim Test As cTest

Using PStream As NamedPipeServerStream = New NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName,   PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.None)
            PStream.WaitForConnection()
            Dim serializer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(cTest))

            Test = CType(serializer.Deserialize(PStream), cTest)
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use WCF Self Hosted Services and let the two communicate using callbacks

Answer (score 0):

This started as a comment but I was running out of room. I am no expert on named pipe communications but, it has been a couple hours, and it may be that that is not really the problem.

You need to first test the serialization/deserialization in the same application. In other words start by taking the pipes out of the picture. This will isolate whether this is a serialization issue or a named pipe issue. Assuming that you code will work when done in the same application, then you need to compare the xml generated by the two applications - have them both do a Serialize. If the xml is identical (which I doubt) then pass it through the pipe and compare it again.

Going further out on a limb here but you may see that the namespace is different for the ctest object. If this is the case it may help to define your shared classes in a library which is shared between the two applications.